# RHEL: can't use ipset utility with error: cannot open session to kernel

Tags: rhel, kernel, iptables, strace, ipset

I'm using a VPS from a VPS provider that run a 2.6 kernel, RHEL with OpenVZ virtualization system. I want to use ipset utility to manage ip sets on my iptables firewall.

This is the error I'm getting when creating an ipset:

```
mindaugas@517713:~$ sudo ipset create cf_ipv4 hash:net 
ipset v6.20.1: Cannot open session to kernel.
```

strace of the command: https://p.defau.lt/?NwzyZkxR_VgekwCRr6YlWg

**Question**: is it even possible to use ipset on such machine with these options? If so - how can I do it?

Mount outout:

```
mindaugas@517713:~$ mount
/dev/simfs on / type simfs (rw,relatime,usrquota,grpquota)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,relatime)
none on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,mode=755)
none on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=4k,mode=755)
none on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=275252k,mode=755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,relatime)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=102400k,mode=755)
```

Here is the relevant information:

```
mindaugas@517713:~$ uname -r
2.6.32-042stab120.3

mindaugas@517713:~$ sudo rpm -qa
vzkernel-headers-2.6.32-042stab120.3.x86_64

mindaugas@517713:~$ ipset --help
ipset v6.20.1
Usage: ipset [options] COMMAND

mindaugas@517713:~$ sudo apt-get install xtables-addons-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
xtables-addons-common is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  dmsetup grub-common grub-gfxpayload-lists grub-pc grub-pc-bin grub2-common
  libdevmapper1.02.1 libfuse2
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Look at that strace again, it doesn't trace the command you want if you try to run sudo in strace like that.

Comment: Thanks for the keen eye @ilkkachu . I corrected the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you're not really using a RHEL kernel (and the fact you used `apt-get` makes me wonder if it is RHEL at all), but an OpenVZ container.  OpenVZ containers rely on features provided by the hosting system's kernel, which in this case doesn't support ipsets.  There's nothing you can install in the container that will make the OpenVZ hosting environment support it, you'll need to talk to your hosting provider to build a kernel with iptables/ipset support.